# fancybox not opening, not sure why

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am trying to open a fancybox with the latest version of fancybox which 2.3.4, The following code does not seems to be working, neither it is throwing an error.

I am just confused why it is not opening the Page:

```
$(".openmails1").click(function() {
            var sender = $(this).attr('data-id');
            var subject = $(this).attr('title');
            var mailid = $(this).attr('rel');
            $.fancybox.open({
            href: '/account/compose.cfm?sender='+sender+'&subject='+subject+'&mailid='+mailid,
            maxWidth    : 600,
            maxHeight   : 900,
            fitToView   : true,
            width       : '70%',
            height      : '80%',
            autoSize    : true,
            closeClick  : false,
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',
            scrolling   : 'no' 
        });
    });
```

Here is how i am calling it

```
<a data-fancybox-type="iframe" title="This is a Welcome Email" data-id="24" rel="myemail@domain.com" href="javascript:void(0);" class="openmails1">Inia Ornit</a>
```

**Update #1**

This is how it is being called:

```
<a data-fancybox-type="iframe" title="This is a Welcome Email" data-id="24" rel="myemail@mtdomian.com~24" class="openmails1">Inia Ornit</a>
```

There are four records with different details, but the class used is same:

Here I am using it like this

```
$(".openmails1").fancybox({
        href: '/account/compose.cfm?sender='+$(".openmails1").attr('data-id')+'&subject='+$(".openmails1").attr('title')+'&mailid='+$(".openmails1").attr('rel')+'&frmaccount=1',
        maxWidth    : 600,
        maxHeight   : 900,
        fitToView   : true,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '80%',
        autoSize    : true,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        scrolling   : 'no' 
    });
```

It is always opening the First one, no matter if i open even the last record, always going as the first record, not sure why it is happening as like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5EV8r/549/) with working example.

```
$.fancybox.open([
{
        href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg',
        maxWidth    : 600,
        maxHeight   : 900,
        fitToView   : true,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '80%',
        autoSize    : true,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',            
        scrolling   : 'no' 
}  
], {
        padding : 0
});
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE #1**

According to your update code I think you have to change to

```
$(".openmails1").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".openmails1").fancybox({
        href: '/account/compose.cfm?sender='+$(this).attr('data-id')+'&           subject='+$(this).attr('title')+'&mailid='+$(this).attr('rel')+'&frmaccount=1',
        maxWidth    : 600,
        maxHeight   : 900,
        fitToView   : true,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '80%',
        autoSize    : true,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
       scrolling   : 'no' 
   });
});
```

You have to create the fancy box to every hyperlink clicked. See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5EV8r/549/) with running example.

Hope it is what yooou're looking for.

Comment: I changed the way you shown me to direct call but now a strange thing is happening: I have added an update to my question

Comment: yes, it is not working on my system or code, so i called directly and it worked, Thanks